# Algebraic Numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I have to talk about algebraic numbers in my abstract algebra course and I don't find good bibliography with more important results, and with good examples, What bibliography do you recommend?
 or what are the most important results

Comment: Neukirch's **algebraic number** theory

Comment: If there's a branch of abstract algebra where there are lots and lots of not-so-deep wonderful results that is Algebraic Numbers, and any more or less decent book in Algebra must mention some of those. For example, you could explain what is the ring of integral (algebraic) numbers in some quadratic extension of the rationals, of the form $\;\Bbb Q(\sqrt D)]\;$ , depending on what is $\;D\pmod 4\;$. From here you could take a little walk to talk about prime numbers that can be written as a sum of two squares...and etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mention that the algebraic numbers form a field and you should also introduce the concept of degree of an algebraic number. It would also be interesting to prove that the set of algebraic numbers is counteble and also to mention that the field of complex algebraic numbers is algebraically closed.

I suppose the Lang's *Algebra* is a good reference for this, but I don't have my copy at hand right now.